Which events are referenced in the Shadow Roll?
The Shadow Roll, also known as the Black Chronology, is an alternate prophecy to the Roll of Years presented in the adventure Cormyr: The Tearing of the Weave.
I have compiled a list of events I think are related to the names of the years according to the Shadow Roll, but I'm missing many. Are there any canon events that might fit those years?

 1352 DR - Year of the Lost King - Gondegal the Lost King conquers Arabel
 1353 DR - Year of Masks - The Night Masks become rulers of Westgate
 1354 DR - Year of Great Reaping - maybe Malthiir becoming ruler in Hillsfar and purging the non-humans?
 1355 DR - Year of Retreat - The elven Retreat reaches its apex
 1356 DR - Year of the Drow
 1357 DR - Year of Spell Flames - Shandril Shessair uses spellfire against Zhentil Keep
 1358 DR - Year of Ascension - Ascension of Mezzanotte, Kelemvor and Cyric
 1359 DR - Year of the Carnival
 1360 DR - Year of Armies - The Tuigan horde fights the crusade
 1361 DR - Year of the Golden Discovery - Matzica discovered
 1362 DR - Year of the Sun
 1363 DR - Year of Winter - ring of Winter found in Chult?
 1364 DR - Year of Lords
 1365 DR - Year of Joyous Elves
 1366 DR - Year of Icy Waters - portal to the plane of ice opens in the Great Glacier
 1367 DR - Year of Unmasking - Kelben Arunsun reveals himself as a masked lord of Waterdeep
 1368 DR - Year of the Sons
 1369 DR - Year of the City's Sorrows
 1370 DR - Year of the Deep War - end of an unspecified submarine war
 1371 DR - Year of the Toppling Towers - the Tower of the Sun in Evermeet is attacked... but it's towers, plural
 1372 DR - Year of Dark Returns - Bane returns, Shade returns
 1373 DR - Year of Madness
 1374 DR - Year of the Unraveling - Maybe attempts at unravelling the Weave?

I'm not interested in later years, but if someone wants to work on them too, here they are:

 1375 DR - Year of Harsh Goals
 1376 DR - Year of False Hopes
 1377 DR - Year of the Black Banner
 1378 DR - Year of Broken Hearts
 1379 DR - Year of Lost Wisdom
 1380 DR - Year of the Dull Blade
 1381 DR - Year of the Fool
 1382 DR - Year of Unwelcome Guests
 1383 DR - Year of Unjust Rewards
 1384 DR - Year of Stolen Thrones
 1385 DR - Year of the Revelation

